# trying to use two way binding in angular, the ngmodel fetched data from database but throws a null value when saved to database

Tags: angular, oracle, spring-boot

I am using `[(ngModel)]` to bind data of one text filed to another but I also want to save that data into the database. When I try that, it throws a null value to the database. Is there a way where I can use `[(ngModel)]` to get and post data. I am working on angular7.

Tried `(ngModelChange)` but not sure how it works when im trying to save the data

```html
<div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
  <select type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" name="user.table_owner" 
          [(ngModel)]="owner" (ngModelChange)="user.table_owner = $event">
    <!-- <input type="hidden" name="owner" [(ngModel)]="owner">-->
    <option>---select---</option>
    <option *ngFor="let owner of listschemas">
      {{owner.user_name}}
    </option>
  </select>

</div>
<!--nested col-sm-6-->
```

expected to post all value

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sample:

```
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedValue" (change)="onChange($event.target.value)">

 <option *ngFor="let owner of listschemas" [value]="owner">
   {{owner}}
 </option>
</select>
```

Get your value in onChange()

Comment: thank you @DimaShah its working.                                                                         
 <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
<select type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" 
[value]='owner' (input)='owner = $event.target.value'
 name="user.table_owner" [(ngModel)]="user.table_owner" (ngModelChange)="user.table_owner = $event" >
 this is the change i made

Comment: Yeah, you missed 'value' I think. If it helped, consider to up vote the answer. Thanks